# Generating sets from imported rules

Tags: database, algorithm

The title is pretty imprecise but I wanted to avoid copying the whole question into it. The sets are actually maps as explained in the first section, the rules come in the second and the problem is that generating everything would mean too much data as detailed in the last section.

### Current state

There are currently tens, soon hundreds of `Customer`s. Each of them may have  thousands of `Item`s and thousands of `Catalog`s. Every item and every catalog belong to exactly one customer and data of different customers don't interact.

Items and catalogs stand in an `m:n` relationship. I see the catalogs as overlapping sets of items and there are some additional details associated. The data come from an import file looking like

```
catalog1 item1 details11
catalog1 item3 details13
catalog2 item1 details12
catalog2 item2 details22
```

In the database, there is a connecting table with three columns just like the import file.

In this example, I retrieve the content of `catalog1` as `{item1: details11, item3: details13}`, etc. Retrieving the content of a catalog in this form is the only important query. So far, it's pretty trivial.

The imports happen a few times a day and I have to update the database content accordingly. The imports are partial in the sense that always only data of a single customer get imported, which means that always only 
a part of the data is influenced. The imports are full in the sense that the import file contains all data of a given customer, so I have to add what's new, update what's changed and remove what's missing in the new import file. Still rather trivial.

### New requirement

Now, groups are to be introduced. Every `Item` may be a member of multiple `ItemGroup`s and every `Catalog` may be a member of multiple `CatalogGroup`s. This information is available separately and the import format hardly changes: In place of a catalog, there may be a catalog group and in place of an item, there may be an item group.

So there are rules like

```
catalog1 item1 details100
catalogGroup1 item1 details101
catalog1 itemGroup1 details102
catalogGroup1 itemGroup1 details102
```

in place of simple connection table rows. These rules may and will conflict and I'm currently inclined to resolve the conflicts by giving precedence to earlier rules (the producer of the import files will accept my decision).

In the `Details`, there may be a piece of information stating that the corresponding item(s) should be excluded from the catalog(s), for example

```
catalog1 item1 EXCLUDE
catalog1 itemGroup1 someDetails
```

means that `catalog1` includes all items from `itemGroup1` except `item1` (the first rule wins).

#### The Problem

Our connection table has already nearly one million rows and we're just starting. If there wasn't the new requirement, it could grow to some hundreds of millions of rows, which is acceptable.

With the new requirement, this number may grow much faster, so that storing the connection table may be infeasible. Already now, this table takes more disk space than all remaining ones together. It's also rather easy to write a rule generating millions of rows by mistake (which will surely happen one day).

All we need is to be able to retrieve the content of a catalog rather quickly, i.e., less than half a second when it contains some hundreds of items. We don't necessarily need to store the table as until now, a few JOINs using an index and some simple postprocessing should be alright.

Many catalogs won't get queried at all, but this doesn't help as we don't know which ones.

The imports needn't be fast. Currently, they take a second or two, but a few minutes would be acceptable.

So I wonder if I should create four tables, one for each combination of `catalog` or `catalogGroup` with `item` or `itemGroup`. Each of the tables would also contain the line number from the import file, so that I could retrieve all rules matching the requested catalog and resolve the conflicts in a postprocessing.

---

Or would be some hacky solution better? I'm a bit inclined to create a single table

```
catalog, catalogGroup, item, itemGroup, lineNo, details_part1, details_part2, ...
```

(where always exactly two of the first four columns are used) as the details are actually tuples of a few parts, which makes the four tables very repetitive. I could extract the details in a new table or blob them together instead.

*I'm looking for some general advice how to tackle it efficiently.*

I guess, some details are missing, but the question is far too long already. Feel free to ask. It's a web application using Java, Hibernate and MySQL, but omitting the tags as it hardly matters.

#### Answers to comments

> Is the query still for catalog contents?

Yes, just like before. The groups are sort of input compression, nothing more.

> And you return an item if it's either connected to a catalog or a group containing a queried catalog?

Or a member of such a group.

> How do item groups work?

Both kinds of groups work the same:

A rule containing a group is equivalent to a list of rules, one for each group member.

Comment: You mean, you can't make more table as lack of memory?

Comment: @AkiraSuzuki Maybe not an absolute lack. But when `catalogGroup1` has 1000 elements and `itemGroup1` has also 1000 elements, then you get `1e6` combinations and storing them is surely inefficient and stupid.

Comment: Yeah, I understood, so you can make only O(n) table.

Comment: Are the identical "detail-designations" (`102`) in the last two lines of the sample rules intentional?

Comment: @greybeard No, it was a mistake, but they may happen to be the same.

Comment: You don't explain how the query is supposed to work with groups.  Is the query still for catalog contents? And you return an item if it's either connected to a catalog or a group containing a queried catalog? How do item groups work? You return all the items in a group if it's connected to a catalog? What happens when you have a connecting row `catalogGroup itemGroup details` and query for a catalog in the group?  This question needs some examples clarifying all this.

Comment: `Our connection table` it may be better to disclose the current model thereof.

Comment: @Gene @Gene I've replied in the text. What I left out should be clarified by the "flattening meta-rule": "A rule containing a group is equivalent to a list of rules, one for each group member". A rule like `catalogGroup itemGroup details` is like `m * n` rules of the form `catalogX itemY details`. I'm still working on the example.

Comment: @greybeard What I called `our connection table` is just like the current state input, one row per `catalog` and `item` (which are foreign keys) containing the details (which are multiple non-key columns).

Comment: `With [imports sporting catalogue- and item-groups, the number of rows may grow much faster (than to an acceptable expected order of some hundreds of millions)]` I don't see how - isn't it the same old items and catalogues, plus the semi-static information *which groups contain what*?

Comment: @greybeard What I mean is the size of the catalog-item-details table where there no groups; when a catalog group contains 20 catalogs and an item group contains 30 items, then in the current format, 600 combinations would get stored.

Comment: `single table [catalog, catalogGroup, item, itemGroup, lineNo, details…]
(where always exactly two of the first four columns are used)` Where exactly one of (*catalog, catalogGroup*) and one of (*item, itemGroup*) are used? (This whole question might be more suitable for [chat].) This "fused table" would turn the "semi-cartesian" joins into self-joins, and leave open the relation between groups and their members.

Comment: @greybeard Every input line specifies either a `catalog` or a `catalogGroup` and the said table has both. So an input like `catalog1 item1 details100` would use the column `catalog` and leave `catalogGroup` empty (`NULL`). An input like `catalogGroup1 item1 details101` would do it the other way round. Similarly for items.

Comment: `more suitable for [chat]` or even [Database Administrators Stack Exchange (DBA)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): `Data Modelling and database-design` are explicitly *on topic* over yonder.

Comment: @greybeard OK, but while the data will sure get stored in the DB, the processing is the interesting part and it may be done in memory (the input data fit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest beginning with normalized tables and a simple join. If I'm reading your question correctly, here's a reasonable schema:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(40)
);

CREATE TABLE catalogs (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(40)
);

CREATE TABLE item_groups (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(40)
);

CREATE TABLE catalog_groups (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(40)
);

CREATE TABLE items_in_groups (
  item_id integer REFERENCES items(id),
  item_group_id integer REFERENCES item_groups(id),
  PRIMARY KEY(item_id, item_group_id)
);

CREATE TABLE catalogs_in_groups (
  catalog_id integer REFERENCES catalogs(id),
  catalog_group_id integer REFERENCES catalog_groups(id),
  PRIMARY KEY(catalog_id, catalog_group_id)
);

CREATE TABLE exclusions (
  catalog_id integer REFERENCES catalogs(id),
  item_id integer REFERENCES items(id),
  PRIMARY KEY(catalog_id, item_id)
);

CREATE TABLE connections (
  catalog_group_id integer REFERENCES catalog_groups(id),
  item_group_id integer REFERENCES item_groups(id),
  details varchar(40),
  PRIMARY KEY(catalog_group_id, item_group_id)
);
```

Note that `items_in_groups` and `catalogs_in_groups` get a singleton entry for each item and catalog respectively. That is, each item is represented by a 1-element group and the same for catalogs.

Now add some data:

```
INSERT INTO items VALUES (1, 'Item 1'), (2, 'Item 2'), (3, 'item 3'), (4, 'item 4'), (5, 'item 5'), (6, 'item 6');
INSERT INTO catalogs VALUES (1, 'Catalog 1'), (2, 'Catalog 2'), (3, 'Catalog 3'), (4, 'Catalog 4'),
  (5, 'Catalog 5'), (6, 'Catalog 6');

INSERT INTO item_groups VALUES
  (1, 'Item group 1'), (2, 'Item group 2'), (3, 'Item group 3'), (4, 'Item group 4'), (5, 'Item group 5'),
  (6, 'Item group 6'), (10, 'Item group 10'), (11, 'Item group 11'), (12, 'Item group 12');

INSERT INTO catalog_groups VALUES
  (1, 'Catalog group 1'), (2, 'Catalog group 2'), (3, 'Catalog group 3'), (4, 'Catalog group 4'), 
  (5, 'Catalog group 5'), (6, 'Catalog group 6'), (10, 'Catalog group 10'), (11, 'Catalog group 11'),
  (12, 'Catalog group 12');

INSERT INTO items_in_groups VALUES
  (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (2, 10), (4, 10),
  (6, 10), (1, 11), (3, 11), (5, 11), (1, 12), (2, 12), (3, 12), (6, 12);

INSERT INTO catalogs_in_groups VALUES
  (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (2, 11), (4, 11),
  (6, 11), (1, 10), (3, 10), (5, 10), (3, 12), (4, 12), (5, 12), (6, 12);

INSERT INTO exclusions VALUES (5, 1), (6, 3);

INSERT INTO connections VALUES (1, 10, 'Details 1-10'), (11, 2, 'Details 11-2'), (12, 12, 'Details 12-12');
```

And query:

```
SELECT cig.catalog_id, iig.item_id, c.details FROM connections AS c
INNER JOIN item_groups AS ig ON c.item_group_id = ig.id
INNER JOIN catalog_groups AS cg ON c.catalog_group_id = cg.id
INNER JOIN items_in_groups AS iig ON iig.item_group_id = ig.id
INNER JOIN catalogs_in_groups AS cig ON cig.catalog_group_id = cg.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT NULL
  FROM exclusions e
  WHERE iig.item_id = e.item_id AND cig.catalog_id = e.catalog_id)
ORDER BY cig.catalog_id, iig.item_id;
```

The result:

```
 catalog_id | item_id |    details
------------+---------+---------------
          1 |       2 | Details 1-10
          1 |       4 | Details 1-10
          1 |       6 | Details 1-10
          2 |       2 | Details 11-2
          3 |       1 | Details 12-12
          3 |       2 | Details 12-12
          3 |       3 | Details 12-12
          3 |       6 | Details 12-12
          4 |       1 | Details 12-12
          4 |       2 | Details 11-2
          4 |       2 | Details 12-12
          4 |       3 | Details 12-12
          4 |       6 | Details 12-12
          5 |       2 | Details 12-12
          5 |       3 | Details 12-12
          5 |       6 | Details 12-12
          6 |       1 | Details 12-12
          6 |       2 | Details 11-2
          6 |       2 | Details 12-12
          6 |       6 | Details 12-12
(20 rows)
```

You could add `items` and `catalogs` to the join to look up the respective names rather than stopping with IDs.

```
SELECT cat.name, item.name, c.details FROM connections AS c
INNER JOIN item_groups AS ig ON c.item_group_id = ig.id
INNER JOIN catalog_groups AS cg ON c.catalog_group_id = cg.id
INNER JOIN items_in_groups AS iig ON iig.item_group_id = ig.id
INNER JOIN catalogs_in_groups AS cig ON cig.catalog_group_id = cg.id
INNER JOIN catalogs AS cat ON cat.id = cig.catalog_id
INNER JOIN items AS item ON item.id = iig.item_id
where NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT NULL
  FROM exclusions e
  WHERE iig.item_id = e.item_id AND cig.catalog_id = e.catalog_id)
ORDER BY cig.catalog_id, iig.item_id;
```

Like so...

```
   name    |  name  |    details    
-----------+--------+---------------
 Catalog 1 | Item 2 | Details 1-10
 Catalog 1 | item 4 | Details 1-10
 Catalog 1 | item 6 | Details 1-10
 Catalog 2 | Item 2 | Details 11-2
 Catalog 3 | Item 1 | Details 12-12
 Catalog 3 | Item 2 | Details 12-12
 Catalog 3 | item 3 | Details 12-12
 Catalog 3 | item 6 | Details 12-12
 Catalog 4 | Item 1 | Details 12-12
 Catalog 4 | Item 2 | Details 11-2
 Catalog 4 | Item 2 | Details 12-12
 Catalog 4 | item 3 | Details 12-12
 Catalog 4 | item 6 | Details 12-12
 Catalog 5 | Item 2 | Details 12-12
 Catalog 5 | item 3 | Details 12-12
 Catalog 5 | item 6 | Details 12-12
 Catalog 6 | Item 1 | Details 12-12
 Catalog 6 | Item 2 | Details 11-2
 Catalog 6 | Item 2 | Details 12-12
 Catalog 6 | item 6 | Details 12-12
(20 rows)
```

As you can see, there are duplicate catalog/item ID pairs with respective details. I suppose this is what you meant by "conflicts." It wouldn't be hard to tweak the query to honor a priority rule to choose one of the alternatives.

Getting a specific catalog's items is just an additional `AND` cause:

```
SELECT cat.name, item.name, c.details FROM connections AS c
INNER JOIN item_groups AS ig ON c.item_group_id = ig.id
INNER JOIN catalog_groups AS cg ON c.catalog_group_id = cg.id
INNER JOIN items_in_groups AS iig ON iig.item_group_id = ig.id
INNER JOIN catalogs_in_groups AS cig ON cig.catalog_group_id = cg.id
INNER JOIN catalogs AS cat ON cat.id = cig.catalog_id
INNER JOIN items AS item ON item.id = iig.item_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT NULL
  FROM exclusions e
  WHERE iig.item_id = e.item_id AND cig.catalog_id = e.catalog_id)
AND cat.id = 3
ORDER BY cig.catalog_id, iig.item_id;
```

And...

```
   name    |  name  |    details    
-----------+--------+---------------
 Catalog 3 | Item 1 | Details 12-12
 Catalog 3 | Item 2 | Details 12-12
 Catalog 3 | item 3 | Details 12-12
 Catalog 3 | item 6 | Details 12-12
(4 rows)
```

As usual, there are several other ways to write the query. I'm no SQL wizard, but SO has many. If this first hack isn't good enough, come back and ask. Denormalization and crazy pre- and post-processing schemes take away future flexibility.

Comment: In this model, `connections` is the object keeping `details`. I read "the group details specifications" as an addition to "details specifications" about a single catalogue, item or both: have entries in the group tables for single catalogues & items. I have been afraid that *includes* and *excludes* are to be nestable arbitrarily: for the resolution mentioned in the question, keep a line# in `connections`. (Never sure whether to use `first…group by` or `not exists…other.line_no < line_no` or …)

Comment: @greybeard The sad thing is that the details of what I need are being changed just now. I guess, you're right with nesting of includes/excludes, so the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` part probably won't work. I'm afraid, I have to wait for more information. It's funny that I missed the idea of representing items as singleton groups. I'm accepting this answer and will post another -- hopefully better -- question, when things get clearer.

Comment: @maaartinus `details of what I need are being changed` life as an IT professional: see this answer's last sentence. Be sure to consider [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @greybeard Yeah if there are serial dependencies imposed by include/exclude, then it's an N-queries problem, so an RDB is probably the wrong way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make catalog relation table like this

Catalog-relation table

```
+--------------------------------------+
| Id |  catalog   | ref_catalog        |
+----+------------+--------+-----------+
| 1  | 'catalog1' |   'catalog1'       |
| 2  | 'catalog1' |   'catalogGroup1'  |
| 3  | 'catalog2' |   'catalog2'       |
| 4  | 'catalog2' |   'catalogGroup1'  |
+--------------------------------------+
```

When calc content of `catalog1`, you can search rows where catalog is catalog1`. Assume that count of this will not big.

Catalog-item table

```
+--------------------------------------+
| Id |  catalog        | ref_item      |
+----+-----------------+---+-----------+
| 1  | 'catalog1'      |   'item1'     |
| 2  | 'catalogGroup1' |   'itemGroup2'|
| 3  | 'catalog1'      |   'item2'     |
| 4  | 'catalogGroup2' |   'itemGroup2'|
+--------------------------------------+
```

Then you search for catalog-item table.

After that, replace itemGroup to separate items.

I think this will take not O(n x n) but O(n).

I recommend you to use ruby on rails model to improve performance.

Without hard algorithm, you can easily make nested structure of tables using `belongs_to`& `has_many`.